# Windows log in prompt showing everytime

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

When I go to run my application on my welcome page(the first page), a windows prompt appears, I then type my information in and another prompt appears, this happens 3 times, then a denied access error appears.

I am using Windows Authentication to run my web application, it is configured as below.

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <authentication>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
  </authentication>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I only have this issue when I have created my own WebSite, when I am running the website on localhost in IIS it runs fine without any prompts.

Comment: You need to more clearly state your problem. When you upload the application to the web server and then access the site, is what then the Windows login prompt appears?

Comment: Sorry, I added a better explanation above.